How to solve `error: Cannot find implementation or library stub for module` mypy error with relative imports?
I have a project with a folder, app, that contains all of my python files.
dir/
- app/
-- test/
--- __init__.py
-- __init__.py
-- main.py

app/test/__init__.py has one line, x=1
main.py contains these lines of code:
from test import x

print(x)

mypy does not like my import of x because it expects it to be from app.test import x
How do I bypass this error in my pyproject.toml config file?
I tried using mypy_path = "/app" but that didn't work.
